# Docker container running node process terminates while waiting for a response to a long request

Tags: node.js, docker, http, request, axios

I have a node script running inside a docker container, that sends a POST request to a server that takes a long time (upwards of 10 minutes) to response.

While waiting for the response, after about 5.5 minutes (consistently) the node process, and in fact the entire docker container, is abruptly terminated. Exit code of `docker run` command is 255.

I have setup a github repo to recreate this issue: https://github.com/hnafar/axios-long-request-issue

In addition to testing this with `axios`, I also tried using the `request` module with same results.

Comment: The container stops because the script terminated. There might be a timeout on the request. You can share a [Minimal Reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here.

Comment: Please read the question in its entirety, I have already setup an example with instructions. I have noted that not only does the node process terminate, the container also terminates, as no other code is executed after node.

Comment: Check `axios` request timeout. Or check if the server has a timeout.

Comment: Axios timeout is set to 0 by default, which indicates infinit timeout, I have tried settings the timeout (both in axios instance config, and on instance.default), but that did not change the results. I understand that a process is terminating, the issue is that nodejs or the parent process should not terminate on timeout. reproducing the issue requires a node server script, a node client script, dockerfile etc. which would be too much to just copy and paste in the question here, hence the github repo.

Comment: What you explain here is not what's written in your script. Where is the part where the process doesn't terminate after the `run` function ?

Comment: What's the error message you have in your node script when it stops ? It works perfectly fine for me. Have you tried your script outside of docker do you have the same problem ?

Comment: there is no "part where the process doesn't terminate". it terminates every time. there is no error message in node. no callbacks are called, no exceptions are caught, and no errors are returned. the node script and the entire container terminates.

Comment: As detailed in the example, if instead of running node directly in docker, I invoke a script that echos a message before and after running the node process, the line after node invocation is not executed - because the entire container is terminated.

Comment: Are you sure you run the same version of the code from the github repository ?

Comment: Hav you tried running the container 10 minutes doing nothing ? `docker run xxx 'sleep 600'`